# How to pass parameters from a job to a FlowStep in spring-batch?

Tags: spring-batch

In a particular spring-batch job, I am using a `Flow` (as it is a reusable sequence of steps) as a `Step`.

I have to pass a set of parameters to the `Flow`.

How do I do that?

My job definition is as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyJob {
   @Bean
   public Job myJob(@Qualifier("myFlowStep") Flow myFlow) {
      return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(someFirstStep())
        .next(myFlowStep(myFlow)).
        .build();
   }

   ...
   @Bean
   public Step myFlowStep(Flow myFlow) {
      // Need to pass parameters to the flow
      FlowStepBuilder flowStepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get("myFlowStep").flow(myFlow);
      return flowStepBuilder.build();
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: What kind of parameters are you referring to, do you mean job parameters? Can you  give an example? Do you need those parameters in the flow definition (`Flow myFlow`) or in the FowStep definition? Can you share the method that defines `Flow myFlow`? I'm asking because if you need those parameters in the flow definition, you can make the method that defines the flow step-scoped to use late-binding of job parameters in it.

Comment: Yes. These are job parameters. It is to be passed to the flow, where in one of its steps, the parameter value determines how the further processing happens in that step. This is being passed as a launch parameter to the job as a job parameter.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification. I added an answer based on your comment.

Comment: if the answer answered your question, please accept it. Please note that accepting an answer is different than upvoting it.

Comment: This is a useful answer definitely. I realised that my question wasn't clear enough, and even my additional detail is not too. But, your answer is good for the clarification I added.

Comment: Let me explain the exact scenario that I am facing.

In a Job, I have 2 steps (`someFirstStep` & `myFlowStep`). The 2nd step is a Flow, as the name suggests. In the class where I am defining the job, I have defined the `FlowStep` using the `myFlowStep()` method that I have mentioned in the question. Is it possible to set any parameters in the `myFlowStep()` method?

Comment: You can use the same approach at the step level, but this time you need to use job scope (as a step bean cannot be step scoped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the flow bean definition step scoped and use [late-binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) of job parameters:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Flow myFlow(@Value("#{jobParameters['name']}") String name) {
    // use job parameter name here
    return null;
}

@Bean
public Step myFlowStep(Flow myFlow) {
  // Need to pass parameters to the flow
  FlowStepBuilder flowStepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get("myFlowStep").flow(myFlow);
  return flowStepBuilder.build();
}
```